# How to properly quote parameters when passing them to another SAS program when called from Linux

Tags: linux, sas, parameter-passing

We're using SAS 9.xxxx.

I'm on a Linux SYSTEM calling a SAS program from a cronfile.

That SAS program is passing arguments to a SAS program it's calling. I having a hard time passing values from one SAS program to another in this method.

Here are the line from each program.

In the cronfile the line looks like this:

```
17 * 18 10 * /usr/bin/bash;. ~/.bash_profile; cd /sasdata/mids_output02/rjs;sas -noterminal -rsasuser -batch -log cron_rpts.log -print cron_rpts.lst -sysparm "param1=2500,param2=2"
 cron_rpts.sas
```

Here are the effective lines from the program its calling.

```
%macro set_constants;
  %global param1 param2;

  %* Get param1 and param2 from sysparm. sysparmpairs does not deal well with quotes, so quote the dates appropriately;
  %sysparmpairs();
  %let param1 = %bquote(')&param1.%bquote(');
  %let param2 = %bquote(')&param2.%bquote(');
%mend;

  %set_constants;                         /* Set macro variables for environment          */
  %put dates=&param1. &param2.;
  /****************************************************************************************************************************************/
  /** Fetch raw pulls of data--transactions (10 min), dnb (33 min), FDIC                                                                 **/
  /****************************************************************************************************************************************/
  systask command 'sas -noterminal -rsasuser -batch -log simple_run_2.log -print simple_run_2.lst -sysparm "param1=&param1.,param2=&param2. simple_run_2.sas' taskname = sim
ple_run_2;
```

When I look at the log afterwards I see the following:

```
WARNING: Apparent symbolic reference PARAM1 not resolved.
^L2                                                          The SAS System                           20:06 Thursday, October 18, 2018

WARNING: Apparent symbolic reference PARAM2 not resolved.
WARNING: Apparent symbolic reference PARAM1 not resolved.
WARNING: Apparent symbolic reference PARAM2 not resolved.
WARNING: Apparent symbolic reference PARAM1 not resolved.
```

How do I pass param1 and param2 in that first call to the simple_run_2.sas program so the parameters will pass their values?

Answer (score 2):

Macro triggers are not evaluated inside of single quotes. Use double quotes instead. For the inner quotes either switch them to single quotes or double them up.

```
systask command 
"sas -noterminal -rsasuser -batch -log simple_run_2.log -print simple_run_2.lst
 -sysparm ""param1=&param1.,param2=&param2."" simple_run_2.sas
" taskname = simple_run_2
;
```

Comment: I think you replied to me on the other page as well. I got the same error. Also I tried it with just the double-double quotes and left the single quotes alone.... Still got the error. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Change the `systask` command to `%put` and see what string you are actually generating.  Are you sure `PARAM1` is defined when you are running that command?  Also your original post had unbalanced quotes. That can get your SAS session into a state that is hard to fix.

Answer (score 0):

OK, so you all were right.

Here is the final solution that passed the values all the way through...

```
systask command "sas -noterminal -rsasuser -batch -log simple_run_2.log -print simple_run_2.lst -sysparm 'param1=&param1.,param2=&param2.' simple_run_2.sas" taskname = simple_run_
2;
```

The original statement for I used for this in was reversed and that seemed to work for just a command call but apparently if you're going to pass parameters and not just the values you have to reverse the quotes. Where the heck would you look something like this up?

Thanks Again!

Comment: The fact that macro triggers do not resolve inside of single quotes is pretty basic to using macro code. http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl//en/mcrolref/69726/HTML/default/viewer.htm#n0700fspmubii5n1vecutttwz93n.htm